# if a laptop is plugged into a power source is it running with ac power or battery

Tags: laptop

I am an old man of 70 years.I use a Tablet in which the operating power is given by the Battery tor which there is an AC Adapter /Charger.The battery although getting charged from time to time gets exhausted after some years and as in most cases as the batteries are Non Replaceable the Tablet has to be replaced.
If I purchase a Laptop( where there is also an AC Adapter cum Charger) whether during running Operating Power will be given by the AC Adapter,if remaining plugged in OR irrespective of the AC Adapter remaining plugged in Power will always come from Battery.
Please help me to take a decision whether to purchase a Laptop.I am interested if the Operating Power is from AC source.With thanks

Comment: Tablets *usually* show an orange power light - instead of green (or red if the battery is low on juice) - while they're being charged.

Answer (score 3):

In the cases of both tablet and laptop, if you're plugged into AC, power will be coming from the AC outlet. This assumes the AC adapter has enough current output to satisfy the unit's needs.

If it doesn't then some current will be coming from the battery to make up the deficit. This is uncommon.[1]

In your case, the batteries in your tablets are failing not because they're being used all the time (they're not) but because they get old - most Lithium-ion batteries in most consumer applications have a lifetime of two to five years even without charge/discharge cycles.

[1] This is the same thing that happens in a car. The only time you're exclusively on battery power is when the engine is off (or, of course, if the alternator has failed). With the engine running the alternator supplies current that both recharges the battery- or, once it's recharged, maintains the charge - and runs the rest of the stuff on the car. If you have something like an enormous aftermarket stereo and/or a weak alternator there can be a current deficit during times of a high electrical load. This means that some of the current needed to run the car will be coming from the battery, meaning that the battery is being discharged. Keep this up for too long and the battery can be drained to the point where the engine will shut down because there isn't enough to run the ignition system, the fuel pump, etc.

Comment: Good, to-the-point and relevant answer. I’m interested: do you have some (credible) source to backup your statement in the last paragraph?

Comment: The statement in the last paragraph is wrong - or at least misleading. Lithium (polymer /ion) batteries have a limited number of charge/discharge cycles - so it does make a difference. That said, even stored in ideal conditions they loose about 20% capacity/year, enen if not being discharged.

Comment: On the other hand, if you partially charge and discharge the battery, ie keep it between 20% and 80% it will greatly prolong the battery life.

Comment: @davidgo “greatly prolong” so how much longer can I expect?

Comment: There is no simple answer as there are a lot of variables, but double the life could be in the ballpark. Have a look at http://batteryuniversity.com/index.php/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries. Note - some laptop makers -like Dell and Lenovo now build this functionality option into the BIOS.

Comment: Sorry but the so-called "Battery University" site is not at all a reliable source.

Comment: @davidgo my last paragraph is not wrong, or misleading, in the context of the OP's question. From his description, he's not discharging/charging his battery, so that's not what's going on. He's running into the "two to five years" lifetime limit that I mentioned - the same that is implied by your "loose [sic] 20% capacity/year", in fact.

Comment: @jamie hanrahan" The bit "regardless of how often you draw from them" implies batteries don't have a limited number of charge/discharge cycles. This is clearly incorrect.

Comment: What do you dispute about the specific "battery University" page I linked to?  (And more generally, why is it not a credible source)

Comment: _"Note - some laptop makers -like Dell and Lenovo now build this functionality option into the BIOS."_ Absolutely no laptop has ever cycled its battery between 20 and 80%. At most they cycle by a few percentage points, or they may allow stopping charging at 80 or 85%.

Comment: _"[...] implies batteries don't have a limited number of charge/discharge cycles. "_ No, it does not imply that. It says there is an upper limit on lifetime even if you don't incur many charge cycles. Incurring many charge cycles would reduce the lifetime from that upper limit. But I see how your interpretation could be drawn. I have reworked the last graf to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Laptop and Tablet charging works the same way.

Simplifying a bit:

The device needs a certain amount of power - which equates to a particular voltage (or set of voltages) to run.

If the device is running off battery, the output voltage of the battery will be increased by circuitry to run the device at the required level, however the voltage of the batteries themselves decreases as they loose power (and this is how the amount of charge left is calculated)

When you have a power supply, it needs to provide the correct voltage.  If there is enough current it will run the computer. If there is more current available then the computer requires to run it will charge the battery with the excess, and if it's not enough, the battery will provide power to top up the difference.

Where you could be running in to issues are that as batteries get old, some of the cells die, and actually suck power from other devices, causing the power supply to need to provide more power then it can, and the unit could eventually die.

Note that while it's not always cost effective, even devices with "non replaceable" batteries can have their batteries replaced ,- it's just a lot harder to fo (exactly how hard depends on the device, but generally easier to do in laptops then tablets, and in non Apple devices (tablets and cellphones and Apple devices sometimes require the screen to be removed using heat, making the process risky and hard - especially waterproof  ones) Most laptops have screws and a case which can be pried open.  Pretty much all devices have a connector which the battery actually plugs in to.